# SQL Join with wildcards

Tags: sql, join

Say I have two tables: table1 as follows

```
Name     |Surname| col1
------------------------
 Bob     |Smith  | BS1
Mary Jane|Jones  | MJ1
```

and table2 as follows:

```
Name     |Surname       | col2
------------------------------
 Bob     |Keller Smith  | BS2
Mary     |Jones         | MJ2
```

What I would like is to JOIN these together to obtain:

```
Name     |Surname       | col1| col2
-------------------------------------
 Bob     |Keller Smith  | BS1 | BS2
Mary     |Jones         | MJ1 | MJ2
```

I tried:

```
SELECT tableb.Name, tableb.Surname, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
LEFT JOIN table2 as tableb
ON '%'+tablea.Name+'%' LIKE '%'+tableb.Name+'%' AND '%'+tablea.Surame+'%' LIKE '%'+tableb.Surame+'%'
```

But these seemed to join everything.

How can I join together columns with wildcards correctly?

Comment: You want an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Tomalak I just tried this and got the same output.

Comment: (i) The `'%'` to the left of the `LIKE`s are most likely superfluous (at best) - but definitely not evaluated as placeholders by the `LIKE` operator. (ii) Is the blank in front of "Bob" intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tableb.Name, tableb.Surname, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
LEFT JOIN table2 as tableb
    ON (tablea.Name LIKE '%' + tableb.Name + '%' OR tableb.Name LIKE '%' + tablea.Name + '%')
    AND (tablea.Surname LIKE '%' + tableb.Surname + '%' OR tableb.Surname LIKE '%' + tablea.Surname + '%')
```

Comment: This didn't work: I got `  Name Surname col1 col2
1 <NA>    <NA>  BS1 <NA>
2 <NA>    <NA>  MJ1 <NA>`

Comment: I just tried it, and it returns exactly the output you expected.

Comment: Oh, could this be an MySQL or SQLite issue?

Comment: I'm using the `sqldf` function in `R`.

Comment: I don't know them. I can only say that this work on SQL Server and should work on MySQL.

Comment: I solved the problem. Your code is correct, but in SQLite (which I only mentioned too late - apologies) the concatenate operator is `||` not `+`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an `INNER JOIN`.

Also note that the percent signs are only recognized on the right hand side of the `LIKE` operator. Joining `Name` with `Surname` also doesn't seem right

```
SELECT 
  a.Name, b.Surname, a.col1, b.col2
FROM 
  table1 AS a
  INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON 
    a.Name LIKE '%' + b.Name + '%'
    OR b.Name LIKE '%' + a.Name + '%'
```

Comment: @Tomalek You are correct about the Name and Surname. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: This didn't work: I got `[1] Name    Surname col1    col2   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data either one of the following works:

```
SELECT tableb.Name, tableb.Surname, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
INNER JOIN table2 as tableb
ON tablea.Name LIKE '%'+tableb.Name+'%'
  AND tableb.Surname LIKE '%'+tablea.Surname+'%';

SELECT tableb.Name, tableb.Surname, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
INNER JOIN table2 as tableb
ON CHARINDEX(tableb.Name, tablea.Name) > 0
  AND CHARINDEX(tablea.Surname, tableb.Surname) > 0;
```

in [SQL Server Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42eb5/1/1) and (with the concatenation adjusted, and `INSTR` taking over for `CHARINDEX`) in [SQL Lite Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/42eb5/3/1).
The latter version might perform better, especially when indices could be used, which (at least in some database systems) are ignored with the `LIKE` operator.