# SQLite wildcards in Join

Tags: sqlite, join, sqldf

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674885/sql-join-with-wildcards) of mine it appears as though my problem is SQLite dependent. I have simplified the problem as follows:

Say I have two tables: table1 as follows

```
Name     | col1
------------------------
 Bob     | B1
Mary Jane| M1
```

and table2 as follows:

```
Name     | col2
------------------------------
 Bob     | B2
Mary     | M2
```

What I would like is to JOIN these together to obtain:

```
NameA     | NameB |col1| col2
-------------------------------------
 Bob      | Bob   | B1 | B2
Mary Jane | Mary  | M1 | M2
```

Using

```
SELECT tablea.Name as NameA, tableb.Name as NameB, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
LEFT JOIN table2 as tableb
ON tablea.Name LIKE tableb.Name
```

I get as output

```
      NameA NameB col1 col2
1       Bob   Bob  B1   B2
2 Mary Jane  <NA>  M1  <NA>
```

which is what I would expect. Now if I use wildcards as follows:

```
SELECT tablea.Name as NameA, tableb.Name as NameB, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
LEFT JOIN table2 as tableb
ON tablea.Name LIKE '%'+tableb.Name+'%'
```

I get:

```
      NameA NameB col1 col2
1       Bob  <NA>  B1  <NA>
2 Mary Jane  <NA>  M1  <NA>
```

It doesn't even match Bob's entries?!

Am I missing something? Is this a problem with `SQLite`?

For completeness, I'm using the `sqldf` function with `R` which uses `SQLite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `||` operator to concatenate strings, not `+`

Comment: This indeed seems to work! Many thanks. I assume that this is the standard concatenate operator in SQLite.

Comment: Actually, it is standard concatenate operator in all SQL dialects I know. It is a little bit inconsistent with most programming languages though...

Comment: Oh. My previous question though yielded answers with `+` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data, you don't need the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT tablea.Name AS NameA, tableb.Name AS NameB, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
INNER JOIN table2 as tableb
ON tablea.Name LIKE '%'||tableb.Name||'%';

SELECT tablea.Name AS NameA, tableb.Name AS NameB, tablea.col1, tableb.col2
FROM table1 as tablea
INNER JOIN table2 as tableb
ON INSTR(tablea.Name, tableb.Name) > 0;
```

Second version for a potential performance gain.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/42eb5/5)